# Install R & RTools from Windows terminal

Tags: r, windows, batch-file

I have a number of people @ work who I'd like to share some R scripts and other assorted goodies.  This requires they have an instance of [R](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/) and accompanying [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) up and running and on their path.  Adding something to the path is pretty easy to script but installing R and Rtools from windows command line is not (at least googling "install R from Windows command line" was not productive).

How can I install R and RTools from the windows terminal into the `C:\` level directory (this can be made into a .bat file for clickable distribution)?

Comment: Have you looked at Tal's [installr](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/installr/index.html) package?

Comment: Also almost surely a duplicate question ...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I am familiar with this but I think this would require an instance of R to already be installed.  I'm trying to allow non technical users in the company to click a .bat to install R using the Windows terminal and once I have R on their system it's all down hill.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I tried below but it seems it fails in non interactive mode as it tries to open a menu
Rscript.exe -e "installr::install.Rtools()"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to learn some bash but this script seems to work:

```
@echo off
If NOT exist "C:\R\R-3.3.0"\ (
bitsadmin  /transfer mydownloadjob  /download  /priority normal  ^
                  https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/R-3.3.0-win.exe C:\\Users\\%username%\Downloads\R-3.3.0-win.exe

C:\\Users\\%username%\Downloads\R-3.3.0-win.exe /VERYSILENT /DIR="C:\R\R-3.3.0"               
) 

If NOT exist "C:\Rtools\"\ (
bitsadmin  /transfer mydownloadjob  /download  /priority normal  ^
                  https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/Rtools33.exe C:\\Users\\%username%\Downloads\Rtools33.exe

C:\\Users\\%username%\Downloads\Rtools33.exe /VERYSILENT /DIR="C:\Rtools\"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `/VERYSILENT` flag, see the [R faq](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Can-I-customize-the-installation_003f)

Edit: forgot the `/DIR="C:\"` flag

Answer (score 1):

FWIW this is what I use.  The chocolatey package for R and Rstudio works fine to get the latest versions.  Then, I use a batch script to get latest Rtools.  Note, I assume you have curl and grep available.  Run as admin, I call this stuff separately from a main script that installs everything, but you could wrap it into one.

Get chocolatey

```
@echo off
setlocal
where choco > NUL || goto :getChoco
goto :EOF

:: chocolatey
:: https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/Installation
:getChoco
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin

:EOF
```

Install R with choco

```
@echo off
setlocal
:: https://chocolatey.org/packages
choco install -y r.project
```

Install latest Rtools

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
pushd "%~dp0"

set "uri=https://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/windows/Rtools/"

:: skip if already installed
if exist c:\Rtools goto :EOF

:: find latest version
for /f "tokens=1" %%i in ('curl -Ls "%uri%" ^|
                          grep -Poi -m 1 "Rtools[0-9]+\.exe"') do (
    set "latest=%%i"
)
if "x%latest%"=="x" (
    echo.error: Latest version of Rtools not found
    goto :EOF
)

:download
if not exist Rtools.exe (
    echo.Downloading Rtools from %uri%%latest%
    curl -Lo Rtools.exe "%uri%%latest%"
)

:install
if exist Rtools.exe (
   Rtools.exe /SILENT /SP- /NORESTART
) else echo.error: Rtools.exe not found
if exist "C:\Rtools" del Rtools.exe

popd
:EOF
```